# How can I clear textboxes so submit button can be re-used?

Tags: c#, forms, object

I am making a program for school in C#, and its purpose is to allow the user to enter film data, which it then puts into an object for that film.  It will also include other functionality such as the user being able to search for a film (it says I have to make 3 film objects and store them in an array all being input by the user).

I have created the first part of the Windows Forms application and it is a screen that gets all the input from the user like the name, director, rating, etc... and there is a submit button which creates the object.  Is there a way, without creating a new form, to use the same screen and clear the textboxes so that when the submit button is clicked again it creates a NEW OBJECT like 'film2'?

Here is my code for the submit button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(dBox_year.Text);

        Film film1 = new Film(tbox_name.Text, tbox_director.Text, tbox_actor1.Text, tbox_actor2.Text, year, tbox_rating.Text);

        filmArray[0] = film1;
    }
```

So, you see how I would like to have the textboxes on the main screen clear themselves, and reuse the same screen but only it would be 'Film film2 = ...' etc.

This is not an assesed piece and we haven't covered this in class yet so I have tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(dBox_year.Text);
    Film film1 = new Film(tbox_name.Text, tbox_director.Text, tbox_actor1.Text, tbox_actor2.Text, year, tbox_rating.Text);
    filmArray[0] = film1;

    //clearing after adding to array
    //or you can just use .Clear() method
    tbox_name.Text = String.Empty;
    tbox_director.Text = String.Empty;
    tbox_actor1.Text = String.Empty;
    tbox_actor2.Text = String.Empty;
    tbox_rating.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tbox_name.Clear() - Clears all text from the text box control.(Inherited from TextBoxBase.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a List instead of an Array, declared at form level:

```
private List<Film> filmList = new List<Film>();
```

Then your button click even would look like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     int year = Convert.ToInt32(dBox_year.Text);

     filmList.Add(new Film(tbox_name.Text, tbox_director.Text, tbox_actor1.Text, tbox_actor2.Text, year, tbox_rating.Text));

     tbox_name.Text = string.Empty;
     tbox_director.Text = string.Empty;
     tbox_actor1.Text = string.Empty;
     tbox_actor2.Text = string.Empty;
     tbox_rating.Text = string.Empty;
     dBox_year.Text = string.Empty;

  }
```

Here you're creating a new Film object and adding it straight away to the list of films, and then clearing the text boxes afterwards.

If there's a specific reason you need an array, then you can always later do

```
filmList.ToArray()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  And how do I refer to a object this way?  I have not declared a name like 'film1', so if I wanted to reference the object how would I do it?

Comment: If you wanted to find a specific film for example, you could do

    var aFilm = filmList.Where(x => x.Name == "Star Wars").FirstOrDefault();
    if (aFilm != null)
    {
        Film film = aFilm as Film;
        MessageBox.Show("You found a film");
     }

Comment: Sorry that looks a bit naff, can't work out how to add code indent in a comment :o)

Answer (score 0):

When Submit button is clicked you want to add the object at the end of the array, not put it at the first position.So you will need an extra variable named, let say, filmCount, which you initialize with 0 and increment on each submit.

```
Film film1 = new Film(tbox_name.Text, tbox_director.Text, tbox_actor1.Text, tbox_actor2.Text, year, tbox_rating.Text);
filmArray[filmCount++] = film1;
```

then you clear the texboxes

```
foreach(TextBox TB in this.Controls)
{
      TB.Text = "";
}
```